# Regular Expression NOT working in a SQLITE query for Android

Tags: android, regex, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am retreiving Phone Numbers from `content://sms/` URI and hence sometimes i am getting alphabets in the value of **address** column for some advertisement messages which i don't want to display. Therefore, i want to display *Phone Numbers ONLY with '+' sign (optional)* and for this the regular expression in my below query is NOT working.

```
    SELECT PHONE FROM TABLE_TEST WHERE PHONE LIKE '%[+]%[0-9]%'
```

Here, i am using the standard SQLITE database for Android. Also tried using REGEXP operator but got some error like: `no such function: REGEXP:` Could anyone please help with the proper Regular Expression.

Comment: @Frank : I have already referred to the question that you have related. The solution of that question is to use **REGEXP** operator instead of LIKE operator but i am getting an error even for that therefore posted this question and also the requirement for regular expression is different in my case.

Comment: This duplicate marking is not correct.  The referenced question is answering for a general Linux environment, while this question is asking specifically for Android.   I do not see any of the answers in the other question pertaining to this aspect.